# Can't login: Unlocking failed

Tags: login, pam, kubuntu

Each time I go to a *sleep* state or just log out, then provide my password in a login form, I get a message **Unlocking failed**. The password I type is correct, because after rebooting the same password works.

*auth.log* output:

```
Apr 14 19:49:12 mathroom unix_chkpwd[15137]: check pass; user unknown
Apr 14 19:49:12 mathroom unix_chkpwd[15137]: password check failed for user (mathway)
Apr 14 19:49:12 mathroom kcheckpass[15077]: pam_unix(kde:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=mathway
```

I am running *Kubuntu* with a 5.11.0-14-generic version of the kernel.

**lsb_relase -a** output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (development branch)
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

(The problem occurred before I upgraded to 21.04, so the problem isn't connected to it)

I am stuck with this problem for about a week and currently found no solution. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: If you can login as root, then check the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files. Make sure there are the same number of entries in both files by typing "wc -l /etc/passwd" and "wc -l /etc/shadow".  And then "awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd > /tmp/p" and "awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/shadow  > /tmp/s". cd /tmp and type "diff p s". There should be no output.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I run your commands, and it shows that they have an identical number of lines and users correspond to each other.

Comment: Check uids are unique. Type "awk -F: '{print $3}' /etc/passwd > /tmp/uids", "cd /tmp", "sort uids > uids.sort"; the do it again with -u option. "sort -u uids.sort > uids.sort.u". Then "diff uids.sort uids.sort.u" which shouldn't return anything.

Comment: And is this a laptop? Can you disable the screen saver? And you can switch between hiberate and sleep and see if there's a difference?

Comment: Still no difference. Yep, and it doesn't let me in even if I just log out and then try to log in. Also, why are you so sure that the problem is with the */etc/passwd* file?

Comment: I'm not sure anything. But you have to start somewhere - the clue was "password" - so the password file needed to be checked. If you don't try something, it's unreasonable to expect anything to change. For instance, instead of letting the computer go to sleep, just logout. Then the next time you need to use it,  see if you can login. If you can, then that narrows the number of possibilities. Also, reboots can mask problems by destroying evidence.

Comment: I fully agree with you. Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again. Overall, it doesn't let me in whenever I leave my desktop session for a while whether I choose a *Sleep* option or *Log out*, so by now, there's no narrowing and any direction I know to move to :(